# Creating my own sectioning command for exercises

Tags: sectioning, exercises

I'm editing a book. What I want is a sectioning command like `\section`, `\subsection`, and friends, to typeset a exercises section at the end of each section of the book. This exercises are in some list environments, and I don't want any additional features to the exercises itself.

I don't want to redefine some of the mentioned commands because I need to use all of them along the edition of the book. So, what I have tried

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}     
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\textsl{\leftmark}}            
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\textsl{\rightmark}}           
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}                         

\newenvironment{ejercicios}{
\newpage

\vspace{0.5cm}

\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\Large Ejercicios \thesection. \rightmark}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\vspace{0.5cm}
}{\newpage}
```

The problem is that the space between the rules and the text are distinct. I've tried to use `\parbox` and try to adjust the spaces between the rules and the text, but this never work because I need (on request to me) the following:

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection
{paragraph}{3}{0cm}             
{0cm}                           
{3mm}                   
{\bf}}  
\makeatother
```

It is to break the line after each paragraph header, I suspect that this affect the use of `\parbox`.

Whatever, my attempt to solution this is inelegant. I want something like `\newsectioncommand` that be independent of the behavior of the `\paragraph` command.

That I want is something that produce

a new page

5mm

rule

3mm

aligned right Ejercicios "section number". "section name"

3mm

rule

5mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following minimal working example (MWE), the command `\sectionexercises` that prints your required "Exercises" layout for the preceding section

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\newcommand{\sectionexercises}{%
  \newpage%
  \kern 5mm
  \hrule
  \kern 3mm
  \null \hfill Ejercicios~\thesection.~\rightmark\par
  \kern 3mm
  \hrule
  \kern 5mm
}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-2]
\sectionexercises
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Here is a question.
  \item Here is a question.
  \item Here is a question.
  \item Here is a question.
  \item Here is a question.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides dummy text, while [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was loaded with the `showframe` package option to highlight the text block borders.

The [`nameref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) provides a more generic way of tapping into sectional titles if you're going to have (say) many sections before typesetting some of the exercises. In that case, you could modify the MWE in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{nameref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref
\newcommand{\sectionexercises}[1]{%
  \newpage%
  \kern 5mm
  \hrule
  \kern 3mm
  \null \hfill Ejercicios~\thesection.~\nameref{#1}\par
  \kern 3mm
  \hrule
  \kern 5mm
}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\label{sec:first}\lipsum[1-2]
\sectionexercises{sec:first}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Here is a question.
  \item Here is a question.
  \item Here is a question.
  \item Here is a question.
  \item Here is a question.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This produces the same result as before, with `\sectionexercises{<lab>}` now taking a label `<lab>` of the corresponding section.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you consider Don Story's `fortextbook` option of his `eqexam` package. 
http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/eqexam.html