# Adding a section of answers for each section of exercises at the end of a book using answers package

Tags: answers

I'm writing a book and for it I have created a little class file.

Each section in the book have (sub-)section of exercises. At the end of all the chapters I want to put a `chapter*` of answers to some of the exercises. Since the exercises are numbered by section (i.e. the exercise's counter reset whenever the section step), I want to group the answers according to the section (and the chapter) of the exercise they answer to. What I want is something like this:

[image: mwe]

Here is the relevant code of the class file. 
The commented lines are my unsuccessful attempts to achieve what I want. I have leaved almost all the packages to see if there some compatibility problem.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2009/09/24]
\ProvidesClass{libro}

\LoadClassWithOptions{book}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[spanish]{babel}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\RequirePackage{thmtools}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{import}
\RequirePackage[font=small]{caption}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{subfig}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{remreset}
\RequirePackage{pb-diagram}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[capitalise,noabbrev,spanish]{cleveref}
\RequirePackage{answers}

\newcounter{cuentaejercicios}[section]
\renewcommand{\thecuentaejercicios}{\Alph{cuentaejercicios}}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=1em,%
  spacebelow=1em,%
  headfont=\normalfont,%
  postheadspace=1em,%
  headpunct={.}]{estilodeejercicio} 
\declaretheorem[
    name={},
    style=estilodeejercicio,
    refname={Ejercicio},
    numberlike=cuentaejercicios
]{ejer}

\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection
    {paragraph}{3}{0cm}             
    {6pt}                           
    {1pt}                           
    {\bfseries}}                    

%\let\c@hapter\chapter
%\renewcommand{\chapter}{
%   \c@hapter
%   \Writetofile{solucionario}{\protect\paragraph*{Capítulo \Roman{\thechapter}.\space 
%   \leftmark}}
%}

\newcommand{\seccionDeEjercicios}{%
  \newpage%
  \kern 5mm
  \hrule
  \kern 3mm
  \null \hfill {\large Ejercicios~\thesection.~\rightmark}\par
  \kern 3mm
  \hrule
  \kern 5mm
  \Writetofile{solucionario}{\protect\paragraph*{Ejercicios\space\thesection.
  \space\rightmark}}
  }

\newcommand{\Z}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand{\N}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}
\newcommand{\nin}{\not \in}
\newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\markboth{\small\textsl Contenidos}{\small\textsl 
    Contenidos}}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}     
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\small\textsl{\leftmark}}            
    \fancyhead[RE]{\small\textsl{\rightmark}}           
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}                         
    \Opensolutionfile{solucionario}
    \Newassociation{respuesta}{Res}{solucionario}
    \renewcommand{\Res}[1]{\textbf{Ejercicio #1.}}
    \Writetofile{solucionario}{\protect\chapter*{Respuestas}}
%   \begin{Filesave}{solucionario}
%   \protect\chapter*{Respuestas}
%   \protect\fancyhf{}
%   \protect\fancyhead[LO]{\small\textsl{Soluciones a los ejercicios}}          
%   \protect\fancyhead[RE]{\small\textsl{Soluciones a los ejercicios}}           
%   \protect\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}                         
%   \end{Filesave}
}
```

The  `\seccionDeEjercicios` command was provided by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32417/4785) answer.

Here is an example of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{libro}

\usepackage[
%           showframe,
            headheight=14.5pt,text={14cm,21cm},centering
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cases}               

\parindent=0cm

\begin{document}
\chapter{Números Reales}
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 

\chapter{Álgebra}
\section{Operaciones con polinomios}
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 

\seccionDeEjercicios
\begin{ejer}
Efectúe las operaciones indicadas. Exprese el resultado como un
polinomio reducido.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\left( x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( 3-2x\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( x-\dfrac{2}{3}\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( 2-x\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( 2x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}+x^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( -x-y\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( -x-y\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( -x-2y-4x\right) ^{3}$
\item $-\left( 2x^{3}-3t^{3}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left(-2+x^{2}-3c-x^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( \dfrac{x+2u^{2}}{3}\right) ^{2}$
\item $-\left( \dfrac{x^{2}-u^{2}}{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( \left( x-r\right)^{2}-r^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $3\left( x-2t\right) ^{4}-3\left(2t-x\right) ^{4}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{respuesta}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $x^{2}+x+\dfrac{1}{4}$ 
\item $4x^{2}-12x+9$ 
\item $ x^{3}-2x^{2}+\dfrac{4}{3}x-\dfrac{8}{27}$
\item $-x^{3}+6x^{2}-12x+8$
\item $ 9x^{4}-3x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}$
\item $ x^{2}+2xy+y^{2}$
\item $-x^{3}-3x^{2}y-3xy^{2}-y^{3}$
\item $-125x^{3}-150x^{2}y-60xy^{2}-8y^{3}$
\item $-9t^{6}+12t^{3}x^{3}-4x^{6}$
\item $9c^{2}+12c+4$
\item $\dfrac{4}{9}u^{4}+\dfrac{4}{9}u^{2}x+\dfrac{1}{9}x^{2}$
\item $-\dfrac{1}{4}u^{4}+\dfrac{1}{2}u^{2}x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}x^{4}$
\item $4r^{2}x^{2}-4rx^{3}+x^{4}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{respuesta}
\end{ejer}

\begin{ejer}
Determine el cociente y el residuo en cada caso.

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\left( 2x^{3}-x^{2}+2x-1\right) \div \left( x-2\right) $
\item $\left( 4x^{3}+2x^{2}-3x-5\right) \div \left( 2x-1\right) $
\item $\left( x^{8}+x^{6}+x^{4}-x^{2}+x\right) \div \left( x-3\right) $
\item $\left( x^{4}-x^{3}-x^{2}+x^{3}+1\right) \div \left( -x+1\right) $
\item $\left( x^{3}+x^{6}+2x^{5}-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2}+x\right) \div \left(x-1\right) $
\end{enumerate}
\end{ejer}

\newpage
\begin{ejer}
Efectúe las operaciones indicadas. Exprese el resultado como un
polinomio reducido.

\begin{enumerate}
\item $-(7x^{2}+3x-4)+(8-x^{2}+5x^{3})-(2x^{3}+3x^{2}-5+8x)$
\item $\left( 11x^{3}-x+7\right) -\left( 2x-4x^{3}-6\right) +\left(7x^{2}-9x+4\right) $
\item $\left( x^{2}+2xy+4y^{2}\right) \left( x-2y\right) $
\item $5a^{3}b^{2}\left( ab^{2}-b+4a\right) -(8a^{3}b^{3}-10a^{4}b^{4})$
\item $(3x^{2}-8x+7)(x^{3}+x)+(2x^{3}-6x+2)$
\item $\dfrac{-36x^{2}y^{2}+24x^{2}y^{2}}{-12x^{2}y^{2}}$
\item $\dfrac{2a^{4}b^{6}c-4a^{5}b^{3}c^{2}+5a^{3}b^{3}c^{3}}{2a^{2}b^{3}c}$
\item $19x^{2}-10x^{3}+x^{5}-14x+6)\div (x^{2}+1-2x)$
\item $(2x^{3}-31x+35-x^{2})\div (2x-7)$
\item $(2-x^{5})\div (x^{2}+1)$
\item $(3x-5x^{2}+9+x^{3})\div (3-x)$
\item $(2x+3)^{2}-(2x-3)^{2}$
\item $(3x+1)(x+4)-(x+2)^{2}$
\item $(7x^{2}-6)(x+1)+(3x-4)^{3}$
\item $-5(a-b^{2})^{2}+(3a+b)^{3}$
\item $(2x^{2}-3)(3x^{2}-5)-(5x^{2}+6)^{2}$
\item $3x(x-2)+(3x-1)(x+5)-(3-x)^{3}$
\item $\left( 7a+1\right) \left( 7a-1\right) -\left( 4a+1\right)^{3}+2a^{2}\left( 
a-\dfrac{1}{4}\right) ^{2}$
\end{enumerate}

\begin{respuesta}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[1.] $3x^{3}-11x^{2}-11x+17$
\item[3.] $x^{3}-8y^{3}$
\item[5.] $3x^{5}-8x^{4}+12x^{3}-8x^{2}+x+2$
\item[7.] $-2a^{3}c+a^{3}b^{3}+\frac{5}{2}ac^{2}$
\item[9.] $x^{2}+3x+5$
\item[11.] $-x^{2}+2x+3$ 
\item[13.] $2x^{2}+9x$
\item[17.] $x^{3}-3x^{2}+35x-32$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{respuesta}
\end{ejer}

\Closesolutionfile{solucionario}

\input{solucionario}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Here the relevant code of my class, with chapters based on `fncychap` (as requested). Some code to differentiate the style of the chapters, was provided by egreg in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55019/4785).

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2009/09/24]
\ProvidesClass{libro}

\LoadClassWithOptions{book}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[spanish]{babel}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\RequirePackage{thmtools}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{import}
\RequirePackage[font=small]{caption}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{subfig}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{remreset}
\RequirePackage{pb-diagram}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[capitalise,noabbrev,spanish]{cleveref}
\RequirePackage{answers}

% Chapters
\ChNameVar{\bf\LARGE}               
\ChNumVar{\LARGE}                   
\ChTitleVar{\LARGE\normalfont}      
\ChRuleWidth{0.5pt}                 
\ChNameAsIs                         
\ChTitleAsIs                        
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{}
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \vspace*{-0.9cm}
    \CTV\raggedleft\mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 2\p@
    \CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space\CNoV\Roman{chapter}.\space\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{-11\p@}
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{40\p@}}
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \vspace*{-9mm}
    \CTV\raggedleft
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{-11\p@}
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{40\p@}}


\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{
    {\csname the#1\endcsname}.\hspace{0.5em}}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection
    {section}{1}{0mm}               
    {6pt}                           
    {1pt}                           
    {\bfseries}}                    

\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection
    {paragraph}{3}{0cm}             
    {6pt}                           
    {1pt}                           
    {\bfseries}}                    

\newcounter{cuentaEjercicios}[section]
\renewcommand{\thecuentaEjercicios}{\Alph{cuentaEjercicios}}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=1em,%
  spacebelow=1em,%
  headfont=\normalfont,%
  postheadspace=1em,%
  headpunct={.}]{estiloDeEjercicio} 
 \declaretheorem[
    name={},
    style=estiloDeEjercicio,
    refname={Ejercicio},
    numberlike=cuentaEjercicios
]{ejer}

\newcounter{definicion}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=6pt,%
  spacebelow=6pt,%
  headfont=\normalfont\bf,%
  notefont=\normalfont\bf,
  notebraces={{}{}},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  headpunct={.}]{estiloDeDefinicion} 
 \declaretheorem[
    name={Definici\'on},
    numberlike=definicion,
    style=estiloDeDefinicion]{defi}


\let\c@hapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 
    \cambiarseccionydefi 
    \let\chapter\c@hapter
  \fi
    \c@hapter
}
\def\cambiarseccionydefi{%
   \renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}{6pt}{1pt}{\Large}}%
   \@addtoreset{definicion}{section}%
   \renewcommand{\thedefi}{\thesection.\arabic{definicion}}%
 }

\newcommand{\seccionDeEjercicios}{%
  \newpage%
  \kern 5mm
  \hrule
  \kern 3mm
  \null \hfill {\large Ejercicios~\thesection.~\rightmark}\par
  \kern 3mm
  \hrule
  \kern 5mm
}


\newcommand{\Z}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand{\N}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}
\newcommand{\nin}{\not \in}
\newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}

\fancypagestyle{respuestas}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[LO]{\small\slshape Soluciones a los ejercicios}%           
    \fancyhead[RE]{\small\slshape Soluciones a los ejercicios}%          
     \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}}

\AtBeginDocument{
     \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\markboth{\small\textsl Contenidos}{\small\textsl 
    Contenidos}}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}     
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\small\textsl{\leftmark}}            
    \fancyhead[RE]{\small\textsl{\rightmark}}           
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}                         
    \Opensolutionfile{solucionario}
    \Newassociation{respuesta}{Res}{solucionario}
    \renewcommand{\Res}[1]{\textbf{Ejercicio #1.}}
    \Writetofile{solucionario}{\protect\chapter*{Respuestas}}
    \Writetofile{solucionario}{\protect\pagestyle{respuestas}}
}
```

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina you can compile with that class to see the style of chapters, stared chapters, sections, and sections of the chapter 1.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution using `titlesec` and not requiring `fncychap`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible solution using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to change the formatting for the sectional units and and `explicit` option  to gain access to the title for the sectional units using `#1` (refer to the package documentation); the `fncychap` package is no longer needed.

The modified file `libro.cls` (the code contains some comments):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2009/09/24]
\ProvidesClass{libro}

\LoadClassWithOptions{book}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[spanish]{babel}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\RequirePackage{thmtools}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{import}
\RequirePackage[font=small]{caption}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{subfig}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{remreset}
\RequirePackage{pb-diagram}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[capitalise,noabbrev,spanish]{cleveref}
\RequirePackage{answers}

\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection
    {paragraph}{3}{0cm}             
    {6pt}                           
    {1pt}                           
    {\bfseries}}                    

\newcounter{cuentaEjercicios}[section]
\renewcommand{\thecuentaEjercicios}{\Alph{cuentaEjercicios}}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=1em,%
  spacebelow=1em,%
  headfont=\normalfont,%
  postheadspace=1em,%
  headpunct={.}]{estiloDeEjercicio} 
 \declaretheorem[
    name={},
    style=estiloDeEjercicio,
    refname={Ejercicio},
    numberlike=cuentaEjercicios
]{ejer}

\newcounter{definicion}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=6pt,%
  spacebelow=6pt,%
  headfont=\normalfont\bf,%
  notefont=\normalfont\bf,
  notebraces={{}{}},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  headpunct={.}]{estiloDeDefinicion} 
 \declaretheorem[
    name={Definici\'on},
    numberlike=definicion,
    style=estiloDeDefinicion]{defi}

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}

% to store the chapter name
\newcommand\mychaptername{}
% to store the section name
\newcommand\mysectionname{}

% chapter formatting
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {}{}{0pt}
  {\titlerule[0.5pt]\vspace{2ex}%
    \filleft{\LARGE\bfseries\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.\space%
    \normalfont\LARGE#1}\gdef\mychaptername{#1}}
  [{\vspace{1ex}\titlerule[0.5pt]}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {}{}{0pt}
  {\filleft\normalfont\LARGE#1}
  [{\vspace{1ex}\titlerule[0.5pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

% change section formatting in chapters 2,3,...
\let\leo@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 
    \changesectionanddefi 
    \let\chapter\leo@chapter
  \fi
    \leo@chapter
}

% format for sections in chapter 1 
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.5em}
  {#1\gdef\mysectionname{#1}}%

% format for sections in chapters 2,3,... 
\newcommand\changesectionanddefi{%
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large}{\thesection}{0.5em}
  {##1\gdef\mysectionname{##1}%
   \@addtoreset{definicion}{section}%
   \renewcommand{\thedefi}{\thesection.\arabic{definicion}}%
}%
}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

\newcommand{\seccionDeEjercicios}{%
  \newpage%
  \kern 5mm
  \hrule
  \kern 3mm
  \null \hfill {\large Ejercicios~\thesection.\space\mysectionname}\par
  \kern 3mm
  \hrule
  \kern 5mm
  \ifnum\value{section}=1 \relax
    \Writetofile{solucionario}{\protect\paragraph*{\chaptername\space\thechapter.\space\mychaptername}}
  \else\fi
  \Writetofile{solucionario}{\protect\paragraph*{Ejercicios\space\thesection.
  \space\mysectionname}}
}


\newcommand{\Z}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand{\N}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}
\newcommand{\nin}{\not \in}
\newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}

\fancypagestyle{respuestas}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[LO]{\small\slshape Soluciones a los ejercicios}%           
    \fancyhead[RE]{\small\slshape Soluciones a los ejercicios}%          
     \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}}

\AtBeginDocument{
     \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\markboth{\small\textsl Contenidos}{\small\textsl 
    Contenidos}}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}     
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\small\textsl{\leftmark}}            
    \fancyhead[RE]{\small\textsl{\rightmark}}           
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}                         
    \Opensolutionfile{solucionario}
    \Newassociation{respuesta}{Res}{solucionario}
    \renewcommand{\Res}[1]{\textbf{Ejercicio #1.}}
    \Writetofile{solucionario}{\protect\chapter*{Respuestas}}
    \Writetofile{solucionario}{\protect\pagestyle{respuestas}}
}
```

The test file, with the new code using `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{libro}

\usepackage[
%           showframe,
            headheight=14.5pt,text={14cm,21cm},centering
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cases}               


\parindent=0cm

\begin{document}

\chapter{Números Reales}
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 

\section{Propiedades de campo}

\seccionDeEjercicios
\begin{ejer}
Efectúe las operaciones indicadas. Exprese el resultado como un
polinomio reducido.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\left( x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( 3-2x\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( x-\dfrac{2}{3}\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( 2-x\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( 2x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}+x^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( -x-y\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( -x-y\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( -x-2y-4x\right) ^{3}$
\item $-\left( 2x^{3}-3t^{3}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left(-2+x^{2}-3c-x^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( \dfrac{x+2u^{2}}{3}\right) ^{2}$
\item $-\left( \dfrac{x^{2}-u^{2}}{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( \left( x-r\right)^{2}-r^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $3\left( x-2t\right) ^{4}-3\left(2t-x\right) ^{4}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{respuesta}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $x^{2}+x+\dfrac{1}{4}$ 
\item $4x^{2}-12x+9$ 
\item $ x^{3}-2x^{2}+\dfrac{4}{3}x-\dfrac{8}{27}$
\item $-x^{3}+6x^{2}-12x+8$
\item $ 9x^{4}-3x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}$
\item $ x^{2}+2xy+y^{2}$
\item $-x^{3}-3x^{2}y-3xy^{2}-y^{3}$
\item $-125x^{3}-150x^{2}y-60xy^{2}-8y^{3}$
\item $-9t^{6}+12t^{3}x^{3}-4x^{6}$
\item $9c^{2}+12c+4$
\item $\dfrac{4}{9}u^{4}+\dfrac{4}{9}u^{2}x+\dfrac{1}{9}x^{2}$
\item $-\dfrac{1}{4}u^{4}+\dfrac{1}{2}u^{2}x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}x^{4}$
\item $4r^{2}x^{2}-4rx^{3}+x^{4}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{respuesta}
\end{ejer}


\chapter{Álgebra}

\section{Operaciones con polinomios}
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 

\seccionDeEjercicios
\begin{ejer}
Efectúe las operaciones indicadas. Exprese el resultado como un
polinomio reducido.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\left( x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( 3-2x\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( x-\dfrac{2}{3}\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( 2-x\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( 2x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}+x^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( -x-y\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( -x-y\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( -x-2y-4x\right) ^{3}$
\item $-\left( 2x^{3}-3t^{3}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left(-2+x^{2}-3c-x^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( \dfrac{x+2u^{2}}{3}\right) ^{2}$
\item $-\left( \dfrac{x^{2}-u^{2}}{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( \left( x-r\right)^{2}-r^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $3\left( x-2t\right) ^{4}-3\left(2t-x\right) ^{4}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{respuesta}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $x^{2}+x+\dfrac{1}{4}$ 
\item $4x^{2}-12x+9$ 
\item $ x^{3}-2x^{2}+\dfrac{4}{3}x-\dfrac{8}{27}$
\item $-x^{3}+6x^{2}-12x+8$
\item $ 9x^{4}-3x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}$
\item $ x^{2}+2xy+y^{2}$
\item $-x^{3}-3x^{2}y-3xy^{2}-y^{3}$
\item $-125x^{3}-150x^{2}y-60xy^{2}-8y^{3}$
\item $-9t^{6}+12t^{3}x^{3}-4x^{6}$
\item $9c^{2}+12c+4$
\item $\dfrac{4}{9}u^{4}+\dfrac{4}{9}u^{2}x+\dfrac{1}{9}x^{2}$
\item $-\dfrac{1}{4}u^{4}+\dfrac{1}{2}u^{2}x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}x^{4}$
\item $4r^{2}x^{2}-4rx^{3}+x^{4}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{respuesta}
\end{ejer}


\begin{ejer}
Determine el cociente y el residuo en cada caso.

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\left( 2x^{3}-x^{2}+2x-1\right) \div \left( x-2\right) $
\item $\left( 4x^{3}+2x^{2}-3x-5\right) \div \left( 2x-1\right) $
\item $\left( x^{8}+x^{6}+x^{4}-x^{2}+x\right) \div \left( x-3\right) $
\item $\left( x^{4}-x^{3}-x^{2}+x^{3}+1\right) \div \left( -x+1\right) $
\item $\left( x^{3}+x^{6}+2x^{5}-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2}+x\right) \div \left(x-1\right) $
\end{enumerate}
\end{ejer}

\newpage

\begin{ejer}
Efectúe las operaciones indicadas. Exprese el resultado como un
polinomio reducido.

\begin{enumerate}
\item $-(7x^{2}+3x-4)+(8-x^{2}+5x^{3})-(2x^{3}+3x^{2}-5+8x)$
\item $\left( 11x^{3}-x+7\right) -\left( 2x-4x^{3}-6\right) +\left(7x^{2}-9x+4\right) $
\item $\left( x^{2}+2xy+4y^{2}\right) \left( x-2y\right) $
\item $5a^{3}b^{2}\left( ab^{2}-b+4a\right) -(8a^{3}b^{3}-10a^{4}b^{4})$
\item $(3x^{2}-8x+7)(x^{3}+x)+(2x^{3}-6x+2)$
\item $\dfrac{-36x^{2}y^{2}+24x^{2}y^{2}}{-12x^{2}y^{2}}$
\item $\dfrac{2a^{4}b^{6}c-4a^{5}b^{3}c^{2}+5a^{3}b^{3}c^{3}}{2a^{2}b^{3}c}$
\item $19x^{2}-10x^{3}+x^{5}-14x+6)\div (x^{2}+1-2x)$
\item $(2x^{3}-31x+35-x^{2})\div (2x-7)$
\item $(2-x^{5})\div (x^{2}+1)$
\item $(3x-5x^{2}+9+x^{3})\div (3-x)$
\item $(2x+3)^{2}-(2x-3)^{2}$
\item $(3x+1)(x+4)-(x+2)^{2}$
\item $(7x^{2}-6)(x+1)+(3x-4)^{3}$
\item $-5(a-b^{2})^{2}+(3a+b)^{3}$
\item $(2x^{2}-3)(3x^{2}-5)-(5x^{2}+6)^{2}$
\item $3x(x-2)+(3x-1)(x+5)-(3-x)^{3}$
\item $\left( 7a+1\right) \left( 7a-1\right) -\left( 4a+1\right)^{3}+2a^{2}\left( 
a-\dfrac{1}{4}\right) ^{2}$
\end{enumerate}

\begin{respuesta}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[1.] $3x^{3}-11x^{2}-11x+17$
\item[3.] $x^{3}-8y^{3}$
\item[5.] $3x^{5}-8x^{4}+12x^{3}-8x^{2}+x+2$
\item[7.] $-2a^{3}c+a^{3}b^{3}+\frac{5}{2}ac^{2}$
\item[9.] $x^{2}+3x+5$
\item[11.] $-x^{2}+2x+3$ 
\item[13.] $2x^{2}+9x$
\item[17.] $x^{3}-3x^{2}+35x-32$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{respuesta}
\end{ejer}

\section{Operaciones con otros objetos}
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 

\seccionDeEjercicios
\begin{ejer}
Efectúe las operaciones indicadas. Exprese el resultado como un
polinomio reducido.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\left( x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( 3-2x\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( x-\dfrac{2}{3}\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( 2-x\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( 2x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}+x^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( -x-y\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( -x-y\right) ^{3}$
\item $\left( -x-2y-4x\right) ^{3}$
\item $-\left( 2x^{3}-3t^{3}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left(-2+x^{2}-3c-x^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( \dfrac{x+2u^{2}}{3}\right) ^{2}$
\item $-\left( \dfrac{x^{2}-u^{2}}{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $\left( \left( x-r\right)^{2}-r^{2}\right) ^{2}$
\item $3\left( x-2t\right) ^{4}-3\left(2t-x\right) ^{4}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{respuesta}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $x^{2}+x+\dfrac{1}{4}$ 
\item $4x^{2}-12x+9$ 
\item $ x^{3}-2x^{2}+\dfrac{4}{3}x-\dfrac{8}{27}$
\item $-x^{3}+6x^{2}-12x+8$
\item $ 9x^{4}-3x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}$
\item $ x^{2}+2xy+y^{2}$
\item $-x^{3}-3x^{2}y-3xy^{2}-y^{3}$
\item $-125x^{3}-150x^{2}y-60xy^{2}-8y^{3}$
\item $-9t^{6}+12t^{3}x^{3}-4x^{6}$
\item $9c^{2}+12c+4$
\item $\dfrac{4}{9}u^{4}+\dfrac{4}{9}u^{2}x+\dfrac{1}{9}x^{2}$
\item $-\dfrac{1}{4}u^{4}+\dfrac{1}{2}u^{2}x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}x^{4}$
\item $4r^{2}x^{2}-4rx^{3}+x^{4}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{respuesta}
\end{ejer}


\begin{ejer}
Determine el cociente y el residuo en cada caso.

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\left( 2x^{3}-x^{2}+2x-1\right) \div \left( x-2\right) $
\item $\left( 4x^{3}+2x^{2}-3x-5\right) \div \left( 2x-1\right) $
\item $\left( x^{8}+x^{6}+x^{4}-x^{2}+x\right) \div \left( x-3\right) $
\item $\left( x^{4}-x^{3}-x^{2}+x^{3}+1\right) \div \left( -x+1\right) $
\item $\left( x^{3}+x^{6}+2x^{5}-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2}+x\right) \div \left(x-1\right) $
\end{enumerate}

\begin{respuesta}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[1.] $3x^{3}-11x^{2}-11x+17$
\item[3.] $x^{3}-8y^{3}$
\item[5.] $3x^{5}-8x^{4}+12x^{3}-8x^{2}+x+2$
\item[7.] $-2a^{3}c+a^{3}b^{3}+\frac{5}{2}ac^{2}$
\item[9.] $x^{2}+3x+5$
\item[11.] $-x^{2}+2x+3$ 
\item[13.] $2x^{2}+9x$
\item[17.] $x^{3}-3x^{2}+35x-32$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{respuesta}
\end{ejer}

\newpage

\begin{ejer}
Efectúe las operaciones indicadas. Exprese el resultado como un
polinomio reducido.

\begin{enumerate}
\item $-(7x^{2}+3x-4)+(8-x^{2}+5x^{3})-(2x^{3}+3x^{2}-5+8x)$
\item $\left( 11x^{3}-x+7\right) -\left( 2x-4x^{3}-6\right) +\left(7x^{2}-9x+4\right) $
\item $\left( x^{2}+2xy+4y^{2}\right) \left( x-2y\right) $
\item $5a^{3}b^{2}\left( ab^{2}-b+4a\right) -(8a^{3}b^{3}-10a^{4}b^{4})$
\item $(3x^{2}-8x+7)(x^{3}+x)+(2x^{3}-6x+2)$
\item $\dfrac{-36x^{2}y^{2}+24x^{2}y^{2}}{-12x^{2}y^{2}}$
\item $\dfrac{2a^{4}b^{6}c-4a^{5}b^{3}c^{2}+5a^{3}b^{3}c^{3}}{2a^{2}b^{3}c}$
\item $19x^{2}-10x^{3}+x^{5}-14x+6)\div (x^{2}+1-2x)$
\item $(2x^{3}-31x+35-x^{2})\div (2x-7)$
\item $(2-x^{5})\div (x^{2}+1)$
\item $(3x-5x^{2}+9+x^{3})\div (3-x)$
\item $(2x+3)^{2}-(2x-3)^{2}$
\item $(3x+1)(x+4)-(x+2)^{2}$
\item $(7x^{2}-6)(x+1)+(3x-4)^{3}$
\item $-5(a-b^{2})^{2}+(3a+b)^{3}$
\item $(2x^{2}-3)(3x^{2}-5)-(5x^{2}+6)^{2}$
\item $3x(x-2)+(3x-1)(x+5)-(3-x)^{3}$
\item $\left( 7a+1\right) \left( 7a-1\right) -\left( 4a+1\right)^{3}+2a^{2}\left( 
a-\dfrac{1}{4}\right) ^{2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{ejer}

\Closesolutionfile{solucionario}

\input{solucionario}
\end{document}
```

An image of the "Respuestas" ("Answers") section showing the desired result:

[image]

Comment: Does this will work with `fncychap`?

Comment: @leo The chapter headinngs in the **Respuestas** section are introduced using `\paragraph*` so it should (in principle) work with `fncychap`. I didn't use `\chapter*` for the chapter titles in the **Respuestas** section because then every chapter would start a new page and that seemed unnecessary.

Comment: Yes it is unnecessary indeed. I'm about to test it with `fncychap`

Comment: Is there another to obtain the current nam of chapters and sections avoinding `titlesec`?

Comment: @leo I don't know, perhaps there's another way, but why don't you want to use `titlesec`? If you want to, you can replicate any of the styles of `fncychap` (which are pretty ugly, by the way) or create a new nice customized format using `titlesec`.

Comment: :-) I agree with you, I don't like that styles, but it was a request. I'll edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: I have updated my question adding the `fncychap` based chapters. By the way, if you can fix the little indentation of the sections headers, it would be great.

Comment: @leo what do you mean with "fix"? Do you want to remove it? I kept it in my answer just because I wasn't sure, but I can easily remove it if that's what you want.

Comment: how do you deal with the different style of sections across chapters? I read the code, I can't find where? And please tell me how to delete the indentation of the sections. Your answer is  great!

Comment: @leo I removed the space in my updated answer (I simply removed the `\hspace*{0.5em}` before `\thesection` inside `\titleformat{}section}`). I don't quite understand what you mean with " the different style of sections across chapters"; could you please elaborate?

Comment: Look at the style of the sections of the chapter 1 and tha sections of chapter 2. They are different, however I don't see any conditional like in the egreg's answer in [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55019/4785)

Comment: @leo I don't see any changes... are you using the updated `.tex` and `.cls` files of my code?

Comment: Yes you are right. There are no changes. I want different sections starting from chapter 1. Look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55019/4785). In there, that was fixed (thanks to egreg) but not using `titlesec`. Can you help me to solve that problem?

Comment: @leo Ah, yes, now I see. Give me some minutes and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @leo Answer updated. I also moved the formatting code from the `.tex` file to the `.cls` file. Additionally, seeing your original code, I saw that you were trying to include the title for each section in the title of its corresponding exercise section; I've also provided this feature in the new code. Let me know if things are OK now.

Comment: Things are very OK now, thanks for your time! I would like to upvote again :-)