# Making boxed "problem" environment and a solution environment

Tags: environments, document-classes

I'm trying to make a template for my homework. I've been using a modification of the Harvey Mudd homework class, but there are some things I don't really like about it (functional and aesthetic).

What I do want are the boxed problem environment and something like their solution environment (which is a lot like amsthm's proof environment).

For the problem environment, I would like to call it, as in the HMC class, by typing

```
\begin{problem}[%problem number%]
%problem statement%
\end{problem}
```

I also wanted the frame to be "3-D," similar to `\shadowbox`, but I can't figure out how to get a more subtle effect.

And is there a way that I can make a solution environment that is essentially identical to the asmthm proof environment? I want to redefine the qed symbol to be `\blacksquare` and be able to use `\qedhere`.

I'm also trying to get spacing similar to that of amsthm's theorem and proof environments (that is, before and after the environments).

If it matters, I am using AMS article. And here are some things I've referred to (and tried) in my attempts at this:

[Problem/solution environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70599/problem-solution-environment)

[Example/Solution Environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19947/example-solution-environment)

[Box around minted environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112559/box-around-minted-environment)

http://www.slideshare.net/linjaaho/how-to-make-boxed-text-with-latex

(On a similar note, how do you look at the "source" [I'm not sure this is the correct term] for a class? I would like to look at how stuff was defined/created in the HMC class, for instance.)

Oh, and a link to the [HMC class](http://www.math.hmc.edu/computing/support/tex/classes/hmcpset/). Which has a [pdf](http://www.math.hmc.edu/computing/support/tex/classes/hmcpset/hw-example.pdf) preview.

EDIT: I think I figured out a solution environment:

```
\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{proof}[Solution]}{\end{proof}}
```

Comment: So, I figured out how to view .cls files (yeah, that was easy). It looks like the HMC class is using minipage to get the boxed problem environment, but they have the option of boxed vs. unboxed. I only want boxed and can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: I would recommend you have a look at [the `mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed).

Comment: your `solution` looks reasonable.  to change the qed symbol, in that definition (within the `proof` environment) add `\let\qedsymbol\blacksquare`.  it will revert to the original as soon as it leaves the environment.

Answer (score 1):

The OP decided to resolve this problem via defining

```
\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{proof}[Solution]}{\end{proof}}
```

See also the comments under the question